# Why does tab_model (sjPlot) re-run MCMC with rstanarm model?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, sjplot, rstanarm

I am creating a table with `tab_model` from the package `sjPlot` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/tab_model_estimates.html).

However, when I use a negative binomial `rstanarm` model object, `tab_model` re-runs MCMC chains.
My actual model takes many hours to run, so this is not ideal for `tab_model` to be doing this, but it doesn't seem to do it for other models (such as with `glmer` in `lme4`).

```
library(rstanarm)
library(lme4)

dat.nb<-data.frame(x=rnorm(200),z=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),50),
                y=rnbinom(200,size=1,prob = .5))

mod1<-glmer.nb(y~x+(1|z),data=dat.nb)

options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
mod2<-stan_glmer.nb(y~x+(1|z),data=dat.nb)
```

Now to create the model tables:

```
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(mod1)
```

[image]

The output is quick, and as expected (although the original model also ran quick, so it is possible that `tab_model` is re-running the model here too).

Now when I try

```
tab_model(mod2)
```

It begins re-running MCMC. Is this normal behavior, and if so, is anyone familiar with a way to turn this off, and just use the model object already created, rather than re-running the model?

Comment: I tried to dig my way through and debug this, but the code was just too chunky for me to figure it out. https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/7f8aa7c3dd7471634359b585312aa5e03edff62c/R/tab_model.R

Comment: I briefly looked at it as well, and just thought I had no chance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** I think this is going to be hard to avoid without hacking both the `insight` package and this one, or asking the package maintainer for an edit, unless you want to forgo printing the ICC, R^2, *and* the random-effects variance. [Here](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/7f8aa7c3dd7471634359b585312aa5e03edff62c/R/tab_model.R#L682-L691), `tab_model()` calls `insight::get_variance()`, which tries to compute variances for the null model so it can compute the ICC and R^2. Computing these variances requires re-running the model. (When it does it for the `glmer.nb`, it goes via `lme4:::update.merMod()` and is quick enough that you don't notice the computation time.)

So

```
tab_model(mod2,show.r2=FALSE,show.icc=FALSE,show.re.var=FALSE)
```

doesn't recompute anything. In theory I think it *should* be possible to skip the resampling/recomputation step with just `show.r2=FALSE, show.icc=FALSE` (i.e. it shouldn't be necessary to get the RE var), but this would take some hacking/participation by the maintainer.

---

Digging in (by using `debug(rstan::sampling)` to stop inside the Stan sampling function, then `where` to see the call stack ...

- `tab_model()` calls `insight::get_variance()` [here](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/7f8aa7c3dd7471634359b585312aa5e03edff62c/R/tab_model.R#L684)
- the `insight::get_variance.stanreg()` method calls `insight:::.compute_variances()`
- ... which calls `insight:::.compute_variance_distribution()`
- ... which (for a log-link count distribution) calls `insight:::.variance_distributional()`
- ... which calls `null_model`
- ... which calls `.null_model_mixed()`
- ... which calls `stats::update()`

Comment: so am I correct in that it appears to be running a null model then, not re-fitting the same model? I am not sure what the function uses the null model for, but it seems as if this should only be useful for some of the output. I will try to look through and see if there is an argument that if turned off would bypass the need for this updating.

Comment: The package maintainer is generally quite responsive, it might be worth opening an issue about this.  I think wanting the RE var but being willing to do without the R^2 or the ICC is a not-unusual use case ...

Comment: Thank you for this, I haven't opened an issue before, but I will look into it.

Comment: For anyone following this thread: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/697